# Admob Unity Android Integration Problems

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am in the process of releasing a game on the Play Store.

I had previously set up AdMob banner and interstitial ads using test ids. These worked perfectly. No problems. The app was then uploaded, with test ids being replaced with the correct add unit ids that I created in AdMob.

The ads did not show up, and the game would crash. The situation then gets weirder: after narrowing down the issue to AdMob, I reverted all add unit ids to their respective test ids. The odd behaviour is still there, even though functionally, the game is identical to what it was before attempting to release it.

One other thing to note is that prior to release, the app was not being signed under publishing settings. I also changed that back to what it was before. I'm not sure if it has something to do with signing the app... Previously compiled versions from before attempting to release still work fine.

Has anyone dealt with such an oddity, and is there a remedy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually I came right with all of this. I'm not sure what exactly happened to cause this. Could have been me accidentally deleting a file or folder. Could have been something got corrupted. Regardless, the solution was simple. Delete everything to do with admob from the unity project. Re-install. All is peachy.